# Is it possible to use multiple tag values for a single tag like in the code

Tags: xml, go, struct, tags

```
type XMLStruct struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name" json:"FirstName"`
    Date    string  `xml:"Date" xml:"pudDate"`
}
```

Comment: Just take a look at the documentation of package encoding/json and encoding/xml and red the parts about the tags, e.g. https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal . Is there any mention of multiple json keys? No. So: No. Always consult the official documentation first. BTW: How should that work? If you marshal such a struct: which json key should be used? And if you unmarshal a json with name and FirstName fields: How would that work?

Comment: There wasn't a mention in the documentation. That is why I asked here. What would be the need of asking then?
I was just hoping to handle multiple keys in a single parameter, because in my case i will either get "date" or "pubDate" and I just need to decode them. In case of marshaling and unmarshaling, I guess prioritization is required.

Comment: Exactly: There is no mention of multiple json keys so multiple json keys are not supported. There are generally no hidden features which happen to be undocumented.

Comment: If the JSON you have to unmarshal is inconsistent: Unmarshal into a struct with _two_ fields mapped: "date" and "pubDate" (maybe both pointer types). Then consolidate in your code into one field you are going to use. This solution is dead simple, requires less than 10 lines of code, is clear and does not do some kind of magic.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using that solution. But as I said before, in my case those two fields will never coexist, so I was trying to find a way to handle both of them in a single parameter.
But as you explained, it would cause other problems in the logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to say no not in this way.

you can do this,

```
type XMLStruct struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name" xml:"name"`
    Date    string  `json:"Date" xml:"Date"`
}
```

or this,

```
type XMLStruct struct {
    Name        string  `json:"name, omitempty" xml:"name, omitempty"`
    Date        string  `json:"Date, omitempty" xml:"Date, omitempty"`
    FirstName   string  `json:"FirstName, omitempty" xml:"FirstName, omitempty"`
}
```

But I don't believe that you can map multiple json names to one struct field and I think that the reason for this would be is what if they both existed in the json structure, which one do you retain and throw away etc.

Answer (score 1):

The field tag of a go-struct can literally have any UTF-8 sequence. This is legal go-code:

```
type XMLStruct struct {
    Name string `g1bb3ri$h...T@g`
}
```

So tags are up for interpretation. The `json` package in the standard library expects tags in a particular format - which maps a single struct field to a single JSON attribute.

If you wanted to support multiple attributes for a single field - one could write their own Marshal/Unmarshal and act on this new tag format. But as some of the other comments/answers have suggested, there is the dilemma of handling conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

There's no definitive answer to this. Struct tags, at the language spec level, are arbitrary text, with no inherent meaning. See [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). This means that, from a language standpoint, `json:"name" json:"FirstName"` is a valid tag, as is any other arbitrary text.

What matters is how code interprets the tags. Since you're talking about the `json` tag, you probably care about the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package in the standard library. How this package interprets tags is described in the documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) and [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal). A duplicate tag like this would, at best, be ambiguous, so one could say it's not supported. Although using such a tag will do *something*. What it does may or may not align with what you expect (depending on what you expect).

But there can be other packages that interpret `json` tags--possibly including one you write yourself. And they can use whatever rules they want, including either permitting or prohibiting multiple tag segments with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same key in key:"value" pair, struct tag look up will only use the first value you specific.

So, Your struct will look like

```
type XMLStruct struct {
    Name    string  `json:"name"`
    Date    string  `xml:"Date"`
}
```

You can read some information in reflect package [StructTag](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag)